# image creation script It creates the correct image in English but in Arabic the coding problem appears

Tags: image, typescript, creation

It creates the correct image in English but in Arabic the coding problem appears

This is the php code for image creation in the script anonymous feedback in this site try it https://saraha.100elkholy.com

```
        // image creation script
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $im             = imagecreatefrompng('./themes/core/images/'.$this->settings->admin_theme.'.png');
    $white          = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black          = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $text           = wordwrap(str_replace('<br />', ' ', $result->message), 150, "\n", true);
    $domain         = ucfirst(get_domain());
    $font           = './themes/core/fonts/Cairo-Black.ttf';
    $image_width    = imagesx($im);  
    $image_height   = imagesy($im);
    $text_box       = imagettfbbox(26, 0, $font, $text);
    $text_width     = $text_box[2] - $text_box[0];
    $text_height    = $text_box[7] - $text_box[1];
    $x              = ($image_width / 2) - ($text_width / 2);
    $y              = ($image_height / 2) - ($text_height / 2);
    $y              = (strlen($text) > 150 && strlen($text) < 360) ? $y/2 : (strlen($text) >= 360 ? $y/3 : $y);
    $file           = time().rand(1,988);
    $filename       = $file.'.png';

    imagettftext($im, 26, 0, $x,  $y,    $black, $font, $text );
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 60,  632,    $white, $font, $domain);

    if (!is_dir('./upload/users/shares/'.$this->user['id']))
        mkdir('./upload/users/shares/'.$this->user['id'], 0777, TRUE);

    imagepng($im, './upload/users/shares/'.$this->user['id'].'/'.$filename);
    imagedestroy($im);

    echo json_encode(array(
                        'flag'      => 1, 
                        'msg'       => sprintf(lang('alert_report_success'), lang('menu_message')),
                        'type'      => 'success',
                        'url'       => site_url('og/'.$this->user['id'].'/'.$file),
                    ));exit;
}

/**
```

Comment: I want help is necessary
   Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: In what way does it create "the wrong image" when you use arabic? Does the font you chose support arabic glyphs (characters)?
You probably want to check the font you use to support all the glyphs you need for whatever string you throw at your script. You likely might need to choose different fonts, depending on the input characters.

The link to your arabic-only site is not exactly helpful in illustrating any problem to people who do cannot read arabic.